# H2OFrame column to array: quickest way?

Tags: python, h2o

Suppose I have an H2OFrame called `df`. What is the quickest way to get the values of column `x` from said frame as a `numpy` array?

One could do

`x_array = df['x'].as_data_frame()['x'].values`

But that seems unnecessarily verbose. Especially passing via a `pandas DataFrame` with `as_data_frame` seems superfluous. I was hoping for something more elegant like, e.g. `df['x'].to_array()`. But I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is another way. However, I'm not sure it's faster. I'm using the h2o.as_list() function to convert a column to a list and then I use the np.array() function to convert the list to an array.

```
import h2o
import numpy as np

h2o.init()

# Using sample dataset from H2O
train = h2o.import_file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_train_10k.csv")


## Creating np array from h2o frame column  
np.array(h2o.as_list(train['x1']))
```